# Using React's useRef hook to handle onKeyDown event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keyboard-events, use-ref, react-forwardref

my first experience using `useRef` and `forwardRef`. I've been given some hints on a potential solution but I'm still a little way off, however the component is small and fairly simple.

What I am trying to do is use `useRef` to pass the result of a `handleOnKeyDown` function, which basically is looking for a keyCode 13 ("Enter" on keyboard) and then "click" the `findGoodsBtnRef` by passing it down into the `CcceAttribute` component via `ref={findGoodsBtn}`

I know what I have at current isn't right (because it doesn't work) and my editor is complaining about my use of `ForwardRef` on the top line, can anyone advise where I'm potentially going wrong on trying to implement this solution? TIA

```
const CommodityCodeLookupAttribute = forwardRef<Props, typeof CcceAttribute>(
  ({ attribute: productLookupAttribute, onChange, ...props }: ref) => {   

  const { object } = useFormObjectContext();

  const ccceAttribute = object.attributeCollection.find(isCcceResultAttribute);

  if (!ccceAttribute) {
    return null;
  }

  const findsGoodsBtnRef = React.useRef();
  const findGoodsBtn = findsGoodsBtnRef.current;


  const handleOnKeyDown = (event) => {
    if (event.keyCode === "13") {
      // event.preventDefault();
      console.log("Default prevented");
      findsGoodsBtnRef.current.click();
      // use the ref that points to the ccce attribute button -> click()
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <StringAttributeDefault
        attribute={productLookupAttribute}
        onKeyDown={handleOnKeyDown}
        {...otherProps}
      />
      <CcceAttribute attribute={ccceAttribute} ref={findGoodsBtn} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Seeing the code of `StringAttributeDefault` and `CcceAttribute` would be kind of necessary to help.
It's kind of unclear also what you're trying to do exactly with calling the click to the ref. Why not call some callback instead?
Also just as a note, you should never use hooks conditionally. `const findsGoodsBtnRef = React.useRef();` should be above the if statement. See rules of hooks. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Comment: What's the reason for `const findGoodsBtn = findsGoodsBtnRef.current;`? Furthermore, it should be `<CcceAttribute attribute={ccceAttribute} ref={findsGoodsBtnRef} />`. Having said that, am I correct if I guess you are trying to check whether a form is being submitted via a keypress on ENTER or a click on a button? In this case it might be easier to handle the `submit` event

Comment: Thanks both, good point in terms of using `findGoodsBtnRef` instead secan - I basically am trying to ensure that in my `handleOnKeyDown` function that we are "clicking" the `findsGoodsBtnRef` - which should then be passed down into the child component..